# Querying Firestore for Boolean property in Asp.net Core/Kestrel Crashes in Linux Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

This is something that works locally in Asp.Net Core 2.0 with C# on IIS Express and Firestore Emulator. 
I am trying the same code base on GCP with Asp.Net core running on Kestrel inside Linux Container in GCP (Kubernetes)

I can confirm that this is specific to Firestore and specific to Querying with Boolean property only as other queries are working fine.

```
        CollectionReference FoosRef = FirestoreDb.Collection(FooKind);
        Query query = FoosRef.WhereEqualTo("IsGoodFoo", true);
        // QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.Offset(offset).GetSnapshotAsync();
        // Query query = FoosRef.WhereEqualTo("FooName", "p,ezbnR33GU_");
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = querySnapshot.Documents.FirstOrDefault();
```

As you can see the commented code works fine in the same setup while querying for "IsGoodFoo" with true fails. I can confirm that the data on Firestore is saved as Boolean only as searching for "true" in Firestore UI doesn't give me any results.
(Querying for true works on Firestore Emulator)

As this is hard crash, I don't see any logs written to StackDriver either, any idea where to check the Kestrel Logs or debug this issue properly.

Comment: Note: this issue is being tracked at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/4561. I suspect the cause is a query that results in nearly 200K results in a snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out not to be "querying using a Boolean property" but "trying to retrieve the results of a query with about 200,000 results".

There are a few options for doing this. The simplest one *when the query still has a small enough number of results* is to use the `StreamAsync` method. Using C# 8 (and version 2.x of the Google.Cloud.Firestore APIs, which support the newer version of `IAsyncEnumerable<>`) you can just use code like this:

```cs
var stream = collection.WhereEqualTo("IsGoodFoo", true).StreamAsync();
await foreach (var document in stream)
{
    // Do whatever with the document
}
```

In my testing (with a 900K+ result query), that timed out after a minute after fetching ~210K items. It's not clear to me yet whether that's expected or not.

A more robust alternative is to issue queries with a limit and a cursor, until the query doesn't retrieve that limit. Here's an example of that:

```cs
int limit = 1000;
var query = collection.WhereEqualTo("IsGoodFoo", true).Limit(limit);

// Used to specify a cursor
DocumentSnapshot lastDocument = null;
while (true)
{
    var queryWithCursor = lastDocument is null ? query : query.StartAfter(lastDocument);
    var querySnapshot = await queryWithCursor.GetSnapshotAsync();
    foreach (var document in querySnapshot)
    {
        // Use the document
    }
    if (querySnapshot.Count != limit)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that while you *can* specify an `Offset` rather than using a cursor, this becomes significantly less efficient when the offset is very large.

Comment: Hey Jon can you look into this one please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906792/firestore-wherein-query-with-fieldpath-documentid-is-not-working

Comment: @skjagini: Please don't use comments on one question to ask for attention on another. I'll look now, but it's not really an appropriate use of comments.