# Firestore WhereIn Query with FieldPath.DocumentId is throwing exception

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to fetch few documents from a Collection based on a list of DocumentIDs and not able to get the following working using WhereIn and FieldPath. Nuget version Google.Cloud.Firestore v1.1.0

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetByDocumentIdWhereIn(IEnumerable<string> documentIds)
{
    CollectionReference ref= FirestoreDb.Collection(_collectionName);
    Query query = ref.WhereIn(FieldPath.DocumentId, documentIds);
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
    ...
}
```

And I am getting the following error when executed with couple of documentIds.

```
RpcException: Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="__key__ filter value must be a Key")
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Grpc.Core.Internal.ClientResponseStream+<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext() in ClientResponseStream.cs
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+<ForEachAsync_>d__174.MoveNext() in ForEach.cs
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query+<GetSnapshotAsync>d__54.MoveNext() in Query.cs
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Hmm. I don't know whether this is a client-side-only restriction, or whether it would fail server-side even if we allowed it client-side. Will investigate. I've created https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/4981 to track this.

Comment: As an aside, do you need any functionality *other* than getting a bunch of documents in one go? `FirestoreDb.GetAllSnapshotsAsync` is probably a simpler way of doing that.

Comment: Ah - I misread the exception. This *is* a server-side restriction already. I'll need to ask the Firestore team about it.

Comment: If I understand the serverside/client side terminology you mentioned, C# libraries are treated as Client libraries which get the data from underlying api (Server-side) ? And because this is underlying api issue, there is no apparent fix for this at this moment?

Comment: Yesterday I released Google.Cloud.Firestore 2.1.0, which should make your original code work.

Comment: Will give a try with new version, :)

Comment: Just noticed that your parameter is an `IEnumerable<string>`. If that's *actually* an array or a list, it'll be fine. If it's a LINQ query, you'll need to wait for 2.2.0, but we'll get there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this answer was written before the release of Google.Cloud.Firestore 2.1.0. As of 2.1.0, the original code should work.

---

This is a server-generated exception, but it's possible to transform the query on the client-side so that it works. If the values provided are `DocumentReference` values instead of just strings, the query works.

That means right now you can fix your code like this:

```cs
CollectionReference coll = FirestoreDb.Collection(_collectionName);
var docRefs = documentIds.Select(id => coll.Document(id)).ToList();
Query query = coll.WhereIn(FieldPath.DocumentId, docRefs);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

In the future we hope to do this for you automatically; progress on this will be tracked on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/4981).

Note that if you *just* want to fetch a collection of document snapshots and you have (or can create) a sequence of `DocumentReference` values, an alternative is to use `FirestoreDb.GetAllSnapshotsAsync`.

Comment: @skjagini: It's an entirely reasonable expectation - I hope we'll be able to make it work in the client libraries in the future, although I wouldn't expect it before June.

Comment: Sounds good, if we can improve the method signature or examples on Firestore website that would be helpful for many. For eg: public Query WhereIn(FieldPath fieldPath, IEnumerable values); was bit confusing at first sight.

Comment: @skjagini: We definitely can't change the method signature - partly for compatibility, and partly because the intention is that it *can* handle a sequence of integers, or strings, or date/time values etc. (And strings would be fine if you'd been querying something other than the document reference, e.g. a text field.)

Comment: @skjagini: Any reason for editing my answer? There *should* be no need to call `ToList()` here. As far as I can see the source should only be evaluated once, with no need to create a list.

Comment: Was getting this error otherwise.  Unable to create converter for type System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Google.Cloud.Firestore.DocumentReference, Google.Cloud.Firestore, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=185c282632e132a0]]
Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.ConverterCache.CreateConverter(Type targetType) in ConverterCache.cs, line 123

Comment: And also regarding method signature, there are two overloaded methods, while one of them supports different datatypes the other one is specifically defined for FieldPath which can be IEnumerable<DocRef>.  public Query WhereIn(string fieldPath, IEnumerable values); public Query WhereIn(FieldPath fieldPath, IEnumerable values);

Comment: @skjagini: The overloaded methods are about the field path you pick, not the values - and `FieldPath` *doesn't* implement `IEnumerable<DocRef>` so there shouldn't be any ambiguity there. Slightly surprised about the `ToList` being needed, but that may be because you're still using the 1.1.0 version - I'd expect it to work in 2.0.0.

Comment: Still the same issue with 2.0.0 version on ToList(), I am ok with it for now though, not much of a performance impact, can always update at later point. :). Thanks

Comment: @skjagini: Okay, thanks. Will look into that as part of fixing the issue. Thanks for testing!

Comment: @skjagini: I now understand why this would currently fail without ToList, and I've got a pull request out to fix that. Not that you need the LINQ query at all as of 2.1.0, but it's nice to be able to use LINQ more often :) https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/pull/5022